# CGAL exact predicate inexact constructions

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal, inexact-arithmetic

I know that it is possible to get exact comparison results without constructing the objects exactly by using `exact_predicate_inexact_constructions` kernel in CGAL. The thing that I wonder is upto which degree I can use the inexact objects to get an exact result. To be more clear, let me give an example: I want to compare two distances, distance between the points p and q1 and distance between the points p and q2. The problem is, both q1 and q2 are not computed yet, they will be found after a few intersection/projection operations. Moreover, for those geometrical operations, there is need to do some vector/direction computations. At the final, I do not need to know none of those interstep objects (none of the vectors, intersection lines, even q1 and q2). The only thing I want to reach is which distance is less than the other. If I define each object with the above kernel and find each interstep object with projection/intersection operation of that kernel and call the comparison function of the same kernel also, would the result that I reach be exact?

Comment: No. As soon as you make a construction, it is inexact, as the name indicates.

Comment: Then, is ```exact_predicate_exact_constructions``` the only way to take exact comparison result?